# Slick slider render slide multiple times in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, loops, slider, slick.js

I am creating slick slider by using reactjs. Slider working fine but it renders slide multiple times. I am looping the slide using map function.

screenshots:

[image]

my scripts:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import '../css/Header.css';
//import SlideItem from './SlideItem';
class SliderSlick extends Component{

    shouldComponentUpdate () {
      // TODO: add proper implementation that compares objects
      return false;
    }

    render() {

       //Slide Items
        var sliderItem = ['slider1.jpg','slider2.jpg','slider3.jpg'];

        var settings = {
          autoplay: false,
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          speed: 1000,

        };


        return (
          <div className="container">
          <Slider {...settings}>
            {
              sliderItem.map((item,index) => {
                return (
                    <div data-index={index} key={index}>
                        <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/images/'+item} alt="Continental GT 650" />
                    </div>
                )
              })
            }
          </Slider>
          </div> 
        );
      }
}

export default SliderSlick;
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using infinite: true, which basically pops slides after one another with the same attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's a feature for having a best performance with animation in last item with next first item !. 
this is just how slick slider infinite-loop works. 
If slider would only clone images/divs it would end up with a performance issue.
Now, if really you don't want clone images/div then you need to set

```
infinite: false
```

or

```
infinite: sliderItem.length > 3 // may be best solution
```